# Communication between Autobahn and Flask/Twisted

Tags: autobahn

I'm building a fairly simple application with Autobahn for WebSocket functionality. It's very similar to a chat server, but one thing I need to do is understand how to accomplish is how to essentially share resources between the WebSocketServerFactory object and my Flask application. The example here:

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_wsgi

shows how to combine both Flask and Autobahn, but in my particular use case, I want to be able to dynamically add a chat room when triggered by an authorized call from the Flask component. Is there any sort of best practice on how to go about communicating between the two components in Autobahn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask is based on WSGI, which is a fundamentally blocking API. This doesn't blend well with Twisted or asyncio (the 2 asynchronous network frameworks supported by AutobahnPython).

Here are 2 options:

- using Twisted `callFromThread` to communicate from a background thread running WSGI to the main thread running Autobahn
- Twisted Klein http://tavendo.com/blog/post/going-asynchronous-from-flask-to-twisted-klein/

Comment: My question really concerns how to go about talking to the WebSocketServerFactory (to add more rooms, delete rooms) from the Flask segment. I was able to share a reference to the WebSocketServerFactory when constructing my Flask blueprint, but I was wondering if there's a better way. Nonetheless, you make a good point about using a blocking API. I based it off this: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_wsgi/server.py Should this example be rewritten to use Twisted Klein?

Comment: The problem isn't about getting a reference to a AutobahnPython object from a Flask object, but that both live on different threads. The reason Flask lives on a background thread pool is that it is blocking code.